# Building azure vue web app using pnpm in a mono repo - with different build steps to local development and deployment

Tags: azure, yaml, vuejs3, azure-web-app-service, monorepo

I have two pipe lines to build my server and one too build my vue web app.
The server one is working fine but now we have moved to using pnpm I cannot get the yaml file to use pnpm no matter what I try (been back and forth with chatGPT) would appriciate if someone is able to look at my mono repo structure and advise how I edit the project for this type of deployment again - its this one that fails azure-static-web-apps-agreeable-hill-0f4662303.yml

https://github.com/nodenogg-in/alpha-p2p/tree/azure-deploy

my co-developer friend who has done the bulk of work has a busy busy few weeks and so I havent been able to chat about the new build stuff which is great locally for starting both the server and the app but it has caused a hiccup where azure treats the as two things

Comment: the error is due to `"nodenoggin": "workspace:0.0.1"` in `package.json`